# Automatically create a CSV file with Javascript data on Github

Tags: javascript, github, download, createfile

I'm working on a Quizz with Html/JS on Github and which will be dedicated to my comrades.
I would like to be able to read everyone’s answers so I thought about creating a text or csv file with their answers that would be saved in a specific directory of the github project.

But I’m a beginner and I don’t know if that’s possible, i’ve seen tracks that use PHP or NodeJs with FileSaver.js, but I haven’t managed any of them because i would like it to be automatic, not to ask the user to download his answers.

If some people knwo how to do it or explain me why it’s impossible and how to do it otherwise it’ll be cool.
Thanks ! ;)

Answer (score 0):

Unless you want to make every person using the quiz a contributor to your Github project (which will require that they sign up for Github accounts and tell you their account name so you can manually grant them permission) and then [use the API](https://docs.github.com/en/rest) to read the CSV file, modify it, then commit the change (and resolve any merge conflicts caused by race conditions): This is not possible (and if you are willing to do that, then it is among the most complex approach that you could take).

If you want to store and aggregate data submitted by visitors to a website then write some server-side code (using whatever language and frameworks you like, PHP and Node.js are both options) and use a web hosting service designed to support them. Github Pages is designed only for *static* pages and doesn't support any form of server-side programming.

Answer (score -1):

Once you store the data in a file, just use git commands to commit and push it.